# In Stross' Merchant Princes series, how does ARMBAND know where to go?

Tags: parallel-universe, teleportation, merchant-princes

In Stross's *Merchant Princes* series, the US Government uses bits of a world-walker's brain *in vitro* to power ARMBAND, which lets their planes cross to Gruinmarkt (World 1).

How does ARMBAND "know" to go to Gruinmarkt? We know by the end of *The Revolution Trade* that there are many possible knots, corresponding to many possible transition edges on the world-graph. What triggers ARMBAND to select that one (or any one)?

Comment: My best guess is that the US scientists measured some kind of neural activity when their captive world-walkers traveled - corresponding to the Clan family knot - and so that's the only trigger pattern they know how to replicate.